# How to know if the activity has returned from a specific intent

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

In my activity I do a lot of operations and set values to different variables fetched from edit text and radio boxes. However one control (Button) triggers a contact picker intent and once a user selects a contact I populate the name and number of this contact in other text boxes. However presumably each time the user returns from the pick contact intent my onCreate seems to execute again, how do I know or where to keep a tab on whether onCreate is being reinstated or not.

My Contact pick code:

```
      Bt3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            flagchk++;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, 1);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `startActivityForResult` in order to get the result in `onActivityForResult`. Anyways, to your question. In order to know if it has called `onCreate` or not, you can declare a following variable: `private boolean onCreate;`

in `onCreate` set this to `true`.

in `onStop` set this to `false`.

Comment: I have used the same to call my contact list, however it seems to call on create again which I dont want, please see my edited question for the specific code.

Comment: are you using this inside a fragment or activity?

Comment: Inside an activity, actually I am using Checkboxes to generate a custom popup( using onCheck Change listener). However when my activity returns from the contacts picker my all onCheckChangeListeners are automatically restarted, which further gives me unwanted popups.

Comment: Is there a way to write code for onCheckChangeListener outside the OnCreate?

Comment: hmm that's strange. are you sure you are not calling finish(); or in manifest sets noHistory="true" ?

Comment: onCreate() is the place where you want initiate all your content and listeners.

Comment: This is my Complete code:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17421827/customized-dialog-box-appears-on-its-own-while-recieving-results-from-contacts

Comment: No my Manifest I have not set no history = true, that will not let the contacts picker return a result.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really know what the problem is. Have you logged inside onCreate() and are absolutely sure that it is being called?

Comment: Yes in Samsung SIII it is being called again, even refreshing my all variables. However in other phones it works just fine.

Comment: Thanks Man, I used a bundle at the end! The issue is resolved :)